How to use FFTConvPDFV1 in zfit?
I'm trying to convolve two PDFs (a CrystalBall and a Gauss) using FFTConvPDFV1 in zfit.
The code I used is
mass_obs = zfit.Space('mass', 0, 1000)

mu_sig = zfit.Parameter('mu_sig', 400, 100, 600)
sigma_sig = zfit.Parameter('sigma_sig', 90, 1, 100)
alpha_sig = zfit.Parameter('alpha_sig', 200, 100, 400, floating=False)  # won't be used in the fit
npar_sig = zfit.Parameter('n sig', 4, 0.1, 30, floating=False)
signal = zfit.pdf.CrystalBall(obs=mass_obs, mu=mu_sig, sigma=sigma_sig, alpha=alpha_sig, n=npar_sig)

mu = zfit.Parameter('mu_res', 0, -1, 1, floating=False)
sigma = zfit.Parameter('sigma_res', 2, 0, 10, floating=False)
gauss_res = zfit.pdf.Gauss(obs=mass_obs, mu=mu, sigma=sigma)
sig_conv = zfit.pdf.FFTConvPDFV1(signal, gauss_res)

I plot the "signal" and "sig_conv" as below,
x = znp.linspace(0, 1000, num=10000)
y = sig_conv.pdf(x)
y1 = signal.pdf(x)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot(x, y, label='model1')
plt.plot(x, y1, label='model2')


but something strange happened, the figure looks like
enter image description here
It looks like that the blue curve is wrong.
If you could give any clue, it will be very appreciated.
